# Javascript jump between intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so , i'm trying to build a custom slideshow with javascript, but i would like to put a custom pause interval for each slide .

let's say i have a slideshow with 3 slides i want it to be like :

```
      30 seconds      8 sec  8 sec
|-------------------|------|-------|
       slide 1       slide2  slide3
```

I want to be able to give a function a list of intervals [5 , 10 , 20] and shuffles a list of slides using that interval list.

I did try to solve this using setInterval with fun , but unfortunately it'sctions calling the next function but as you know it's not scalable to many slides,

### Code

```
// slid is a class having all slides
function bringback() {
    slid.goToSlide(0);
}
function bringback2() {
    slid.goToSlide(2);
    setTimeout( bringback, 8000 );
}
$(document).ready(function(){  
    setInterval(function(){
        slid.goToSlide(1);
        setTimeout( bringback2, 8000 );
    }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: Please provide your relevant code and your attempts at a solution

Comment: An array or times and an index should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout):

```
;(function(){

  var intervals = [5,10,20];

  (function update(next){
    // Pick a slide and update the slideshow here

    setTimeout(function(){ 
      update((next + 1)%intervals.length);
    }, intervals[next]*1000);
  })(0);

})();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Axn89/)

You could make it choose a random slide or just iterate through the slides in order, like so:

```
;(function(){

  var intervals = [5,10,20];

  (function update(next){
    slid.goToSlide(next);

    setTimeout(function(){ 
      update((next + 1)%intervals.length);
    }, intervals[next]*1000);
  })(0);

})();
```

Comment: @TheOtherGuy You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. Thanks for the compliment :)